# Park multiple domains to elastic beanstalk [Same path]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I know about creating hosted zones and parking the domain.
But it has a limit of 500 as per the aws route 53 FAQ .
I want to park x number of domains to the eb env.
Please do not suggest url forwarding  .

Any help or hints would really help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DNSLimitations.html#limits-api-entities) is a **soft limit**. You can request a limit increase by following the link in the docs.

Comment: thank you. So, there's no other way except creating multiple hosted zones?

Comment: @XenonCI Don't know of other way, apart from not using R53. You can look for other domain registrars.

Comment: Let's say i don't used R53, how to point the domain to eb? I am new to eb. @Marcin

Comment: I though R53 is the only way to point domains to eb.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But i would prefer using other registrar , so, just adding the CNAME will do the work? After that SSL certificate (from ACM) in the load balancer. Correct? @Marcin

Comment: @XenonCI Yes, other DNS service providers can be used. R53 is the most convenient as it integrates well with other AWS services.

Comment: @XenonCI CNAME will not work as it can't be used with root domains. But ALIAS record can, such as in [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10128/2237/how-to-create-an-alias-record/).